# How do I implement Observer design pattern for a Multi-Threaded Java server?

Tags: java, database, multithreading, observer-pattern

I have the following situation:

A Java server has to respond to multiple clients through sockets. The server responses are, in fact, results of database queries. The clients can also demand tohe server to update the database content.

A new thread is assigned for each new connected client. I want each connected client to "know" when other clients update the database content.

I have tried to implement the Observer design pattern to achieve this but I didn't succeeded: the observers are not notified when an update query is applied to the database -> the update method in observer is never called. 
The actual Java code is complicated so I will try to summarize the Observer design pattern implementation through the following code snippet:

```
public class DBDataPersistance<E> extends Observable implements DataPersistance<E>{
private static Connection conn;
protected Statement stmt;
protected ResultSet res;
protected List<Observer> obs = new LinkedList<Observer>();

//The method that alters the database;
public void updateData(String parameters) {
    try {
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers();
        this.stmt.executeUpdate(parameters);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void addObserver(Observer o){
    System.out.println("New observer added!");
    this.obs.add(o);
    }
}

//MultiThreadServer implements Runnable and Observer and contains an instance of DBDataPersistance
public class PizzaMultiThreadServer implements Runnable, Observer{
    private static PizzaDBDataPersistance sDB;
    private static ObjectOutputStream sendClientResponse;
    private static ObjectInputStream isc;


    MultiThreadServer(Socket s) {
        this.cSocket = s;
        try {
            sendClientResponse = new ObjectOutputStream(cSocket.getOutputStream());
            sendClientResponse.flush();
            isc = new ObjectInputStream(cSocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    sDB = new DBDataPersistance("jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOPPC;database=BD;integratedSecurity=true;");
        while (true) {
             //client-server communication
             MultiThreadServer newClient = new MultiThreadServer(csock);
             sDB.addObserver(newClient);
             Thread t = new Thread(newClient);
             t.start();
        }
    }


 @Override
 public void run() {
 //Client server communication on a separate thread
 }


 @Override
 public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
         System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId()+ ":Noticed on update!");
 }
}
```

Could you tell me where I am wrong and indicate me the steps to correctly implement the Observer design pattern in this case?

Many thanks.

Comment: Multithreaded code is very difficult to get right, even for good programmers.  My advice would be to make this work synchronously without threads.  Measure performance, see if you need asynch processing, and only add threads if you need to.  You might be making the problem harder than it needs to be without need.  Layer the problem better: Put the database code in a separate class that you can test separately and put aside.  If you do need threading, better to use the Executor classes rather than raw Thread.  There have been a lot of changes to make concurrency easier.  Use them.

Comment: In addition to what duffymo said, using an observer pattern for database updates sounds like a dubious solution.  Most dbs use caching and even allow the cache to be temporarily stale (out of date) for more performance.  Many types of updates don't matter if the user sees data that is a few seconds old.  Design is a must here.

Comment: Thanks for the opinions.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is due to the fact that you `override` the method `addObserver` in your class `DBDataPersistance` such that you have no `Observers` registered into the class `Observable` so you have no `Observer` that can be notified.

The code should be:

```
public void addObserver(Observer o){
    // Calls the method addObserver of the class Observable
    super.addObserver(o);
    System.out.println("New observer added!");
    this.obs.add(o);
}
```

Please note that you don't need to manage the list of `Observer` yourself as it is already managed by the class `Observable` so you should get rid of `obs`, the code then will be:

```
 public void addObserver(Observer o){
    // Calls the method addObserver of the class Observable
    super.addObserver(o);
    System.out.println("New observer added!");
}
```

Last remark about your code is the fact that you are supposed to call `executeUpdate` before notifying the `Observers` so it should be:

```
public void updateData(String parameters) {
    try {
        this.stmt.executeUpdate(parameters);
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers();        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I made the suggested modifications and it works. Thanks again. :)

Comment: The observer list is of no interest as it is already managed by `Observable`, it can be removed.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès that's correct, I updated my answer to indicate that, thx

Answer (score 0):

Do not implement that yourself, there are many libraries that can help you with that.

I would suggest https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

(Not sure if this should be an answer or a comment sorry for that)

Comment: It's good to know for future ocasions. Thanks for the suggestions.